# PHP isset : is this redundant?

Tags: php, forms, isset

When my form has been submitted i always check if the form is `isset` and then check if all fields are also `isset`

This is my `php` code :

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
  if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    // process
  }
}
```

My question is, does my first check of `isset` is if the form itself is submitted and then check again for each `input` if it `isset` or if the moment i use

`if(isset($_POST)) { }`

it will actually check of the fields inside that form?

i hope you get my point thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code a `'`
 is missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `$_POST` is always set, so first statement is not necessary.. Check only if specific fields are set.

**EDIT:** As noted in comment, `isset()` give you only information, if some variable is set, not if it has some value. `empty()` can tell you, if you have something in it.

**EDIT 2:** Just to be sure if `empty()` will or will not notice you on undefined POST field, try this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump(empty($_POST['undefined']));
```

You will see that `empty()` works with undefined indexes too.

Comment: @hek2mgl It checks the `isset()` part as well :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a post index has been sent, reagardless if it contains an empty string or some data use `array_key_exists()`:

```
if(array_key_exists($_POST['foo']) && array_key_exists($_POST['bar'])) ..
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien wait.. Can you explain your code? Maybe I'm blind but I don't get it

Comment: Even am confused with the question, if the question is about `isset()` than it's already answered, if it's about keys or the values being blank, than `in_array()` would be helpful, am sure keys has nothing to do here though :) it's all value and isset..

Comment: I guess the question was just about "should I test isset($_POST)". The answer is no, because it will be always set. Then you added the `empty()` hint, which can be helpful if OP wants to make sure that no empty fields had been submitted. (Otherwise not) ..  To your code, I meant, I got `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading` when executing your code.

Comment: to be true, I posted it without reading it once, so I deleted back, and I saw you answered somewhat similar, so won't matter if I duplicate the same thing :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I still would like to see your solution, as I'm not sure what you wanted to show. I'm asking because it might be a good attempt, `array_key_exists()` is very slow..

Comment: It was with `in_array()` for the empty value check, cuz I thought he was more keen to see whether any key value is empty, but turns out he was just refactoring his code as he selected the other answer as correct :)

Answer (score -1):

wtf??

**BETTER** use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
// process
}
```